# Are local tuple arguments of a function ever optimized away?

Tags: scala, tuples, compiler-optimization, case-class

In scala, very often I find myself passing a tuple to a function. For example, as the accumulator element to a collection. The simplest case is:

```
val x = (a,b)
def f(x : Tuple[Int, Double]) : Int
```

Will the compiler ever optimize this into

```
def f(a : Int, b : Double) : Int
```

In other words, will **locally** scoped product types (`Tuple`s, `case class`es or anything deriving from `Product`) ever be optimized to avoid heap allocation via `new`?

Another question would be whether this applies to the return types too?

Comment: Scala compiler never does that directly in the way you mention. Oracle JVM does escape analysis and may (or may not) allocate tuple and boxed primitives on the stack instead, but there's no guarantee it will. Scala can also compile to JS and native, so it depends on runtime you mean.